# Images are not resizing outside of mobile view - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-scaling

I am working on a `container-fluid` full width site with a fixed side bar using bootstrap.

http://nickmask.github.io/index.html

My images in my `mainContent container` are not re-sizing at the tablet size or above. If I drop down to mobile size they resize fine.

I have tried adding `img-responsive`, but no luck. Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-8 fluidContainer" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="mainHeading">
      <hr class="separator" id="topSep">
      <h1>Recent Work</h1>
      <h2>Blogs and projects recently completed</h2>
      <hr class="separator" id="botSep">
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
      <article>
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/700/280" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>This article</h2>
        <p>   
          Remember outweigh do he desirous no cheerful. Do of doors water ye guest. We if prosperous comparison middletons at. Park we in lose like at no. An so to preferred convinced distrusts he determine. In musical me my placing clothes comfort pleased hearing.
        </p>     
      </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have `width: auto;` on your `#mainContainer`. Remove `width: auto;` from `#mainContainer` and add the class `img-responsive` to the images and it should work.

Comment: Huh, I feel a bit stupid now but that did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap css `max-width: 100%;`. you change `width: 100%;` and same height. set width and hight.